# Как сделать чтобы при открытии формы scroll элемента panel выставлялся в нужное положение?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать чтобы при открытии WinFoRm scroll элемента panel выставлялся в нужное положение?

**СКРИН**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужное - это какое? Нужно чтоб был видим какой-то определенный контрол?

Comment: @Андрей приложил скрин

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод `ScrollControlIntoView()`

Например:

```
panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(groupBox2);
```

Но имейте ввиду, что это нужно сделать после того как вся форма уже загрузилась (в `Form_Load` не сработает)

Comment: не могли бы вы дополнить ответ, как реализовать событие `после того как вся форма уже загрузилась`. А то, что-то "поиск" вроде ничего не выдаёт.. PS Пока только осваиваю..

Comment: Я добавил в `Form_Shown`. А вообще вот: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Можно задавать любую желаемую позицию скрола:

```
panel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 100);
```